# Safest method to pass data back to creating class?

Tags: java, object, parameter-passing

I’m working on a project where users may be able to instantiate their self-created objects from within mine (that is, create their own “control” they add to my GUI interface).

To get data back to my object, I know that when theirs is created I can pass mine as an object to access public methods, etc.

Is this safe? Or should I be looking at using listeners or something else? Though I’d still need to pass my object for them to add the listener?

I could simply regularly poll them to see if there’s any updates To data, but do I need to worry at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Have your instantiating class implement a `CallbackInterf` interface, and just give that to the instantiated class to pass data back to it, via a callback?
the new class doesn't need to access all of the instantiator's methods right?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. Thanks, I’ll take a look at that!